Factorization of the characteristic polynomial of a graph
Let G be a graph and $p(G,x)$ its characteristic polynomial.
I read in an article that if G is the disjoint union of two subgraphs H & K then $p(G,x) = p(H,x)p(K,x) $
I want to show that if $G\setminus D$ is the subgraph obtained by deleting the vertices in D for some $\textit{D} \subset V(G)$ then $p(G,x) = p(G\setminus D,x)p(D,x)$, where D is the subgraph induced by the vertices in D.
My question is: Does G being the disjoint union of H & K mean that they have no vertex in common, or must there be no edges between vertices in H and K?
The result is immediate if the former is true but I'm not sure what the autor meant.
Any insight is helpfull although a proof would be much appreciated.

It's the latter. The former is not true, and the thing you're trying to prove is also false.

Consider that if $p(G,x) = p(G\setminus D,x)p(D,x)$ were true in general, then by repeatedly taking $D$ to be a single vertex, you could prove that $p(G,x)=x^n$ for any $n$-vertex graph, which is clearly not the case.

Random graphs tend to have irreducible characteristic polynomial. https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.04049

Let $G$ be the disjoint union of $H$ & $K$. It means that they have no vertex in common.
we can name the vertices in a proper way, then build the block matrix, like this:(block matrix with 4 blocks)
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
H & 0 \\
0 & K
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Clearly, the characteristic polynomial as follow:
$$P(G, x) =p(H, x) p(K, x)$$

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
